# Is there a Server.Transfer() alternative to get a user's previous page?

Tags: asp.net, server.transfer

Is there any way to know the previous page a user visited (on my site of course) from server side? I know I can do it if user was redirected before with Transfer() method. Does any history exist during session?

Comment: maybe from the Referer in the request headers? But than can be faked....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx to get previous user client page.

Comment: Note that `UrlReferrer` is not reliable - it may be `null` or it may be inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

Is the page that you looking for inside your own site?  If so, you can do this to enable different reactions for different pages.  If it is outside of your site, then I would go with UrlReferrer like Trekstuff mentioned.

```
If Not PreviousPage Is Nothing Then
  Dim str As String = PreviousPage.AppRelativeVirtualPath
  If str = "~/(DESIRED URL)" Then
  End If
End IF
```